# Combo Box selected Item gives Exception

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a combobox with the following items:

```
1024
2048
4096
8192
```

I am using the following code to retrive an item selected by user:

```
String cach = form.comboCache.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

But this line is giving an exception `Null Reference Exception, Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Answer (score 2):

If that line is giving a `NullReferenceException` then one of the following is true:

- `form` is null
- `form.comboCache` is null
- `form.comboCache.SelectedItem` is null

Either reason about your code to work out which of those is the case, or simply put a breakpoint on that line and debug into it, then look at `form` in the Watch window.

Once you've worked out which part is null, you need to step back and work out *why* it's null - because presumably you were expecting it not to be null. We don't really have enough context here to help you work that out (we don't even know what kind of app you're writing - web, WinForms etc) - but hopefully it'll be obvious from the debugger.

Comment: I got it, the form object by which i am referring is null, when i wrote the same line outsite the static Main methods domain, it worked correctly.Thanks